# Trabajando con android studio me sale este error

Tags: android

Al momento de ejecutar mi aplicación el `LogCat` me arroja este error:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.testgarakumba1/com.example.testgarakumba1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.testgarakumba1/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.testgarakumba1/com.example.testgarakumba1.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

El MainActivity si que está creado

Comment: Será más fácil ayudarte si copias/pegas el código del MainActivity donde sospechas te da error y del AndroidManifest.xml, que es donde parece que apunta el error.

Comment: Mira que la activity esté declarada en el Manifest

Comment: publica tu activity y tu manifest, de lo contrario no sabremos dónde se aloja el error

Answer (score 0):

Me parece extraño que indique MainActivity no existe, limpia y genera nuevamente tu proyecto y si usas android Studio anterior a 4.0 debes deshabilitar "Instant Run":

`File` > `Settings` > `Instant Run` . **deshabilita "Enable Instant Run"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]